# How to customize URL interpretation on MobaXterm

Tags: shell, ssh, xterm, mobaxterm

I'm using MobaXterm for some time now (it's a really good tool), but i having some issues with the hyperlink interpretation on terminal.

Sometimes i receive a link like this:

`https://XXXXX:1234/4529089718/l/?session=user%12345`

But the terminal only allow the click until the second ":", and the clickable link will be something like this:

`https://XXXXX`

How do i make the correct interpretation work for all the URL including the ":" and possibly another chars?